# How to set Class-Path in Java manifest.txt

Tags: java, eclipse

My project structure is as below

```
TestProject
    |
    |---- src
    |      |
    |      |---- package
    |               |
    |               |---- main.java
    |
    |---- externaLibs
               |
               |---- lib.jar
```

The manifest.txt is as below:

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0

    Created-By: 1.7.0_06 (Oracle Corporation)

    Main-Class: package.Main

    Class-Path: ../externaLibs/lib.jar ./externaLibs/lib.jar /externaLibs/lib.jar externaLibs/lib.jar lib.jar (However I've tried these class paths to the lib.jar, none of them works)
```

Exporting my project with Eclipse, then, when executing the command: java -jar main.jar, the exception about being unable to find the external lib.jar always occurs:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/example/SomeClassInLib
```

The output jar structure is as below:

```
testproject.jar
    |
    |---- externaLibs
    |        |
    |        |---- lib.jar
    |
    |---- pasckage
    |        |
    |        |---- main.java / main.class / and so on...
    |
    |---- META-INF
             |
             |---- MANIFEST.MF
```

What is the problem with the manifest.txt ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: please add some statement about the file structure where the generated main.jar is located and it's relation to the externalLibs folder.

Comment: Add the output jar structure. Please check, thanks

Comment: The problem is that your externalLibs folder is inside the jar file. The standard classloaders do not support this "fat jar"

Comment: Thanks. But it still fails even I move the externaLibs folder outside the jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eclipse when you export, there is an option to export as Runnable Jar File. You can use the library handling radio buttons in the wizard to choose how the dependencies are handled. With the first two options, the dependencies get added into your jar. The third option creats an output folder and places the dependency jars in an accessible location for your jar.

Comment: Try to use the option to export as Runnable Jar File. However, in the filed of Launch configuration, my project doesn't appear so unable to select and export. I also notice that some projects appear and some don't. What causes this difference ? Thank you

Comment: Ok I see. So the launch configurations are how eclipse decides the main class of the project. So if you execute the main method, you will see that it appears as a run configuration. So go ahead and first run the main method once. Then the menu "Run"-->"Run Configurations..." will bring up a list of run configurations. You should see your class there. You can make adjustments to it there if required, name etc.

Comment: Also, you will only see the option for Java projects other projects will not appear.